# What are the search parameters to get Xcode 4.2?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, xcode, macports

What are the search parameters to get xcode 4.2?  I see xcode 6, and searched for 4.2...and got back hundreds of results.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

```
My system:




System Software Overview:

  System Version:   Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 11.4.2
  Boot Volume:  Untitled
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:  a MacBook
  User Name:    thufir (thufir)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
  Time since boot:  7 minutes
```

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?  BTW When I type in Xcode 4.2 it only shows 4.2 and 4.2.1.

Comment: @njboot typing Xcode 4 produces 37 results and not are all the Xcode.app so I wouldn't say "Pops right up" since what he's looking for in in the second page of results.  He say's he's looking for Xcode 4.2 so that's what he should be typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you don’t have an Apple Developer account, then you must create one to legally access this content. [Sign up is free.](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action)**

1. Sign into your Apple Developer Account and go to the [Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)
2. Type in the following query: `Xcode 4.2`
3. The query should return two results:

   [image]

   Download the latest.dmg